# Comment last/first line of file in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

I would like to have a key shortcut that comments out the first and last three lines of a file.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a macro such as `Packages/User/comment_first_last.sublime-macro`:

```
[
        {"command": "move_to",  "args": {"to": "bof", "extend": false}},
        {"command": "insert",   "args": {"characters": "# "}},
        {"command": "move_to",  "args": {"to": "eof", "extend": false}},
        {"command": "move_to",  "args": {"to": "bol", "extend": false}},
        {"command": "insert",   "args": {"characters": "# "}},
        {"command": "move",     "args": {"by": "lines", "lines": true, "forward": false}},
        {"command": "move_to",  "args": {"to": "bol", "extend": false}},
        {"command": "insert",   "args": {"characters": "# "}},
        {"command": "move",     "args": {"by": "lines", "lines": true, "forward": false}},
        {"command": "move_to",  "args": {"to": "bol", "extend": false}},
        {"command": "insert",   "args": {"characters": "# "}}

]
```

Then create a keymapping in `Preferences -> Key Bindings - User`:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+i"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/comment_first_last.sublime-macro"}}
```

So you have a file

[image]

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to trigger the macro:

[image]

You may want to change the `#` character in the macro file to whatever your comment character is.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at [this](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/macros.html).  I would just navigate to a line, insert comment characters, navigate to another line, insert comment... etc. etc.

Good luck.